# java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, grpc, amazon-emr

Was trying to connect to grpc from spark. Its working fine on my local but while testing it in AWS EMR ( after doing sbt assembly)- got conflict with spark package in emr,so shaded the libraries which are already present in spark

```
assembly / assemblyShadeRules  := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("io.grpc.**" -> "shade.io.grpc.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("io.netty.**" -> "shade.io.netty.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> "shade.com.google.protobuf.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "shade.com.google.common.@1").inAll
)
```

Using Spark version: 3.1.1
scala version : 2.12.10
sbt version : 1.6.2
AWS EMR version :6.3.1
Java version : 8
these is the error we are getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 27) (ip-10-50-133-143.ec2.internal executor 2): java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow
Exception Details:
  Location:

        shade/io/grpc/internal/TransportTracer.getStats()Lshade/io/grpc/InternalChannelz$TransportStats; @102: lload_3
      Reason:
        Exceeded max stack size.
      Current Frame:
        bci: @102
        flags: { }
        locals: { 'shade/io/grpc/internal/TransportTracer', long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd }
        stack: { uninitialized 52, uninitialized 52, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd }
      Bytecode:
        0x0000000: 2ab4 0041 c700 0914 0042 a700 0f2a b400
        0x0000010: 41b9 0047 0100 b400 4a40 2ab4 0041 c700
        0x0000020: 0914 0042 a700 0f2a b400 41b9 0047 0100
        0x0000030: b400 4d42 bb00 1259 2ab4 004f 2ab4 0051
        0x0000040: 2ab4 0053 2ab4 0055 2ab4 0057 2ab4 0059
        0x0000050: 2ab4 0033 b900 5f01 002a b400 612a b400
        0x0000060: 632a b400 651f 21b7 0068 b0            
      Stackmap Table:
        same_frame(@13)
        same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@25,Long)
        append_frame(@39,Long)
        same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@51,Long)
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) are you using? Some shading bugs have been fixed, so ensure you're using the latest version (currently 2.0.0).
I have seen very similar exceptions with outdated versions of the plugin.